# Replace Saturday & Sunday Date with Previous Friday Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a generic date table.

I'm trying to achieve the following output

[image]

I cant seem to get the right output by using this case staement

```
SELECT 
DayOfWeek,
ShortDate,

CASE WHEN (DayOfWeekNumber = '1' OR DayOfWeekNumber = '7') -- Saturday or Sunday
THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ShortDate FROM DateTable DD WHERE DayOfWeekNumber = 6) 
ELSE ShortDate  END AS ExpectedShortDate

FROM DateTable
WHERE ShortDate >= '3/13/2020'
```

Here is what I see as the output

[image]

I understand why I'm getting '1/5/1900', this is because thats the first date in my table that is a Friday. However, for my purposes, every Saturday and Sunday date should be replaced with the previous Friday date.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
DayOfWeek,
ShortDate,

CASE 
WHEN (DayOfWeekNumber = '1') -- Sunday
THEN (select FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, -2, ShortDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS date)
WHEN (DayOfWeekNumber = '7') -- Saturday
THEN (select FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, -1, ShortDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS date) 
ELSE ShortDate  END AS ExpectedShortDate

FROM DateTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just check the day of the week and apply offset accordingly, within a conditional expression.

Assuming that you are using SQL Server (as the use of `select top 1` in your query suggests):

```
select
    date,
    case datepart(weekday, date)
        when 7 then dateadd(day, -1, date) -- saturday
        when 1 then dateadd(day, -2, date) -- sunday
        else date
    end expected_date
from dateTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

While watching a Brent Ozar training video, he recommended creating a Date table (dbo.T_DATE) that will store n number of attributes including day of the week, quarter, first day of month, etc.  Having such a table will make these types of activities a snap and save the next developer from having to read some nasty code.

It may look like this:

CREATE TABLE DBO.T_DATE(..., DATE DATETIME2, DAY_OF_WEEK VARCHAR(100), ...)

From there, I'm assuming you can take it the rest of the way.  Also, the dbo.T_DATE table can also serve as a numbers table, which comes in handy when you want to prevent looping your queries...